# we say "tous les données" or "toutes les données"

Tags: orthographe

I wonder which one is correct "toutes les données" or "tous les données"
I suspect that "toutes" is correct because "donnée" is female, however I hear a lot of people said tous so, what do you think ??

Comment: You are incorrectly correct. ***Toutes** les données* because *donnée* is **feminine** ;-)

Comment: I didn't get you ??

Comment: I  strongly suspect that your title is responsible for the remark! (incorrectly correct)

Comment: You wrote *female* instead of *feminine* which is incorrect. But *Toutes les données* is correct.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Seriously? OP knows that "données" is feminine and is wondering if there is nonetheless a grammatical rule that would somehow require to say "tous les données", apparently after hearing a native speaker say it. Where would one learn that in a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

As written above, we say "toutes les données" because "donnée" is feminine. But I'm curious, where did you heard a lot of people say "tous les données" ? Can I have the context ? Maybe there was another group of masculine nouns in the same sentence ?

Comment: While I do not think the OP being in that particular context, do not forget that *donné* can be a masculine noun => One could hear *tous les donnés*, but, of course, in some very spécific context. http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/donn%C3%A9 (III.A.)